# Yum api get packages from group list

Tags: linux, python-2.7, yum

How can I get list of packages in "base" group?

```
import yum
yb = yum.YumBase()
yb.disablePlugins()
yb.setCacheDir()
repos = yb.repos.listEnabled()
destdir="/tmp/repo"
arch = "x86_64"
repoid="Myrepo"
baseurl="http://mirror.yandex.ru/centos/6.6/os/%s" % (arch)
imgurl="%s/images/install.img" % (baseurl)
repopath="Myrepo"
cachedir = "/tmp"     #yum.misc.getCacheDir()
yb.repos.setCacheDir(cachedir)
newrepo = yum.yumRepo.YumRepository(repoid)
newrepo.name = repopath
newrepo.baseurl = baseurl
newrepo.mirrorlist = None
newrepo.basecachedir = cachedir
newrepo.metadata_expire = 0
newrepo.timestamp_check = False
yb.repos.add(newrepo)
yb.repos.enableRepo(newrepo.id)
yb.repos.doSetup()
yb.cleanRpmDB()
XM = yb.selectGroup(grpid='base')
print XM
```

Output :

[]
 Warning: Group base does not have any packages to install.

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: What version of CentOS is this running on? It is looking at a CentOS 6 repo but is tagged with a newer version of python than CentOS 6 has by default. Also this exact code works for me here on a CentOS 6.5 system.

Comment: cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 6.6 (Final).
These packages are already installed.
I need a list of all packages of the group.

Comment: Turn debugging up on `yb` and see what it says is going on? If you add a `.repo` file for this repo can you get yum itself to get the group listing?

Comment: Cahnge base to gnome.
Gmone not installed.
Code return packages list.

Comment: There's no `gnome` group in that repo's comps.xml file. Can you disable every other repo in that code and see if things change?